# Cropping image from uiimagepickerviewcontroller in selected area

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

how to crop image from `UIImagePickerController` in selected area when capturing image. overlayview to `UIImagePickerController`

Comment: What have u done? : Check [resize-and-crop-an-uiimage-from-uiimagepickercontroller](http://www.mapostolakis.me/blog/2014/5/24/resize-and-crop-an-uiimage-from-uiimagepickercontroller)

Comment: i have capture image from `UIImagePickerController` but i should require cropped area part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the Code

```
-(UIImage *)centerCropImage:(UIImage *)image
{
   // Use smallest side length as crop square length
   CGFloat squareLength = MIN(image.size.width, image.size.height);
   // Center the crop area
   CGRect clippedRect = CGRectMake((image.size.width - squareLength) / 2, (image.size.height - squareLength) / 2, squareLength, squareLength);
   // Crop logic
   CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], clippedRect);
   UIImage * croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
   CGImageRelease(imageRef);
   return croppedImage;
}
```

After that in imagePickerViewDelegate Method

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey: @"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [self centerCropImage:image]; //Just give your image here for cropping
    yourImage.image=image; 
    picker.delegate =self;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: i have one question when i click on capture button at that time which method called...??

Comment: your button action method called.After that when you select the image from Photo Library and through the Camera,imagePickerViewDelegate Method is called.That method is didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.

Comment: when UIImagePickerController is open at that time capture button click that time which method is used...??

Comment: At that time it is calling the  following line of Button Action

Comment: UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

Comment: When you are picking the image,didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo called.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2_7JhOCyGypVV9LVXFGeUY4SDA/view?usp=sharing) see this image

Comment: when you pick that didFininshPickingMediaWithInfo is called.

Comment: ya i know but i should require when click on capture button

Comment: It depends on UIImagePickerView Delegate Methods.It is not related to our button action coding. didFininshPickingMediaWithInfo Method handles that.